# Dataframe with "Sparse" Vector groupBy aggregation,not dense Vector in spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a Spark dataframe that looks as follows,it filled with **sparse Vector but not dense Vector**:

```
+---+--------+-----+-------------+
|id |catagery|index|vec          |
+---+--------+-----+-------------+
|a  |ii      |3.0  |(5,[3],[1.0])|
|a  |ll      |0.0  |(5,[0],[1.0])|
|b  |dd      |4.0  |(5,[4],[1.0])|
|b  |kk      |2.0  |(5,[2],[1.0])|
|b  |gg      |5.0  |(5,[],[])    |
|e  |hh      |1.0  |(5,[1],[1.0])|
+---+--------+-----+-------------+
```

as we all know,if i try like this

`val rr=result.groupBy("id").agg(sum("index"))
scala> rr.show(false)`

```
  +---+----------+                                                                
  |id |sum(index)|
  +---+----------+
  |e  |1.0       |
  |b  |11.0      |
  |a  |3.0       |
  +---+----------+
```

but how can I use "groupBy" and "agg" to sum Sparse Vector?
I want the final dataFrame like this:

```
      +---+-------------------------+                              
      |id |   vecResult             |
      +---+-------------------------+
      |a  |(5,[0,3],[1.0,1.0])      |
      |b  |(5,[2,4,5],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
      |e  |(5,[1],[1.0])            |
      +---+-------------------------+
```

I think  VectorAssembler() may solve this, but I don't know how to write code, should I use udf?

Comment: Shame, would have loved to read the answer...